# What aws services can I use to deploy node.js app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to aws. I want to deploy a node.js app. I know about `EC2` but what other available services can I use for that ?

Also, what can I use deploy postgresql database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS provides multiple solutions to deploy nodejs applications. This page provides details all required details https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/deploy-nodejs-web-app/

Overall Available Options are:

- Elastic Beanstalk
- Node.js Stack on the AWS Marketplace (EC2 but ready to use stack)
- Amazon Lightsail (VPS Solution similar to Digital Ocean / Vultr , comparatively cheaper than EC2)

For the postgres

- Deploy it on EC2 instance : Unmanaged Solution : https://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_RDBMS_PostgreSQL.pdf
- Deploy using AWS RDS : Managed & Preferred Solution : https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/what-is-postgresql/

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in deploying a web application coded in Node.JS, you can deploy that to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Elastic Beanstalk is a quick way to deploy apps to the cloud. You can locate more information about this use case here:

[Deploying Node.js applications to Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.html)

If you want to work with postgresql in the cloud, you use the AWS Relational Database Service (RDS). You can setup a number of different databases. To learn how to setup postgresql, see:

[Create and Connect to a PostgreSQL Database](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-connect-postgresql-db/)